# VBS Script to open Outlook without 'Choose Profile' prompt

Tags: vbscript, outlook

My script right now runs an Excel VBA code that needs Outlook to be open, so I'd like to use the script to open Outlook, however the script always stops at the 'Choose Profile' prompt

Here's the script:

```
Dim eApp

Set eApp = GetObject("C:\Users\rliu\Desktop\Book5.xlsm")
eApp.Application.Run "Book5.xlsm!SubFolders"

set eApp = nothing
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your script above does not touch Outlook in any way. Secondly, the prompt will always be shown at Outlook startup if "Prompt for  profile" checkbox is checked in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles.